# Хранение пароля

Tags: spa, криптография

Подскажите варианты хранения пароля в виде bcrypt в браузере для SPA сайтов.

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, зачем вам реализовывать хранение пароля в браузере?

Comment: для того что бы человек постоянно не вводил логин и пароль после обновления

Comment: Но ведь он и так не будет этого делать, хранение пароля сейчас встроено в любой современный браузер и автоматически работает на любом сайте без каких-либо действий с вашей стороны

Comment: да, согласен, но как тогда реализовать автовход?

Comment: В SPA это обычно делают через JSON Web Token (JWT), а пароли никто никогда в здравом уме не хранит, потому что это небезопасно (не считая встроенной в браузер функциональности и специальных менеджеров паролей)

Comment: тогда  подскажите как можно оставаться аутентифицированным после обновления страницы?

Comment: Про JWT в интернете информации достаточно, чтобы вы почитали самостоятельно, а не ждали ответов здесь :)

Comment: к тому же я храню не чистый пароль а хешированый

Comment: Хранить хешированный bcrypt'ом пароль в браузере опять же крайне небезопасно. Не изобретайте собственные решения, касающиеся «безопасности», не понимая принципа их работы, и почитайте про JWT :)